# TypeError: string indices must be integers Python

Tags: python, google-maps, for-loop

I am trying to create a .csv file of parsed information of geocoded data from the google API geocoding service. I want to parse out the address information to be in separate columns. My script runs fine till location data where I get Type error. Can anyone help me and modify my script so that I can include this data into my table?

##Here is my script

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests 
import geocoder
import time 
import json 
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/albertgonzalobautista/Desktop/workingbook.csv') # define CSV to be read to be geocdoed 

# create new columns for the output CSV 
df['geocode_data'] = ''
df['address']=''
df['street_number']=''
df['street_name']=''
df['postalcode']=''
df['city']=''
df['st_pr_mn']=''
df['country']=''
df['location_lat']=''
df['location_lon']=''

# Create function that handles the geocoding requests 

average = 0
def reverseGeocode(latlng): #defines reverse geocoding function 
    #Set parameters
    start = time.time()
    result = {} #create empty list 
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0}&key={1}' #Access URL for Google Geocoder API 
    apikey = 'XXX' # Set you API Key taken from Google API website and your Google Developers Account 
    request = url.format(latlng, apikey) 
    #delays responses so that it does not over     
    data = json.loads(requests.get(request).text)
    if len(data['results']) > 0:
        result = data['results'][0]
    #global average #if not work delete first char(uncomment)
    average = time.time() - start
        
    return  result
    
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if average < 0.3 : time.sleep(0.3 - average) #0.3 is period time (min= 0.2 max = free)
    
    df['geocode_data'][i] = reverseGeocode(df['lat'][i].astype(str) + ',' + df['lon'][i].astype(str))
    
        
for i, row in df.iterrows():
if 'address_components' in row['geocode_data']:
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        df['address'][i] = row['geocode_data']['formatted_address']
        
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'street_number' in component['types']:
            df['street_number'][i] = component['long_name']
            
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'route' in component ['types']:
            df['street_name'][i] = component['long_name']
            break
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'route' in component ['types']:
            df['street_name'][i] = component['long_name'] 
            
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'postal_code' in component ['types']:
            df['postalcode'][i] = component['short_name']
            break
        
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'locality' in component ['types']:
            df['city'][i]= component['short_name']
            break
        
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'administrative_area_level_1' in component ['types']:
            df['st_pr_mn'][i] = component ['long_name']  
            break
        
    for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
        if 'country' in component ['types']:
            df['country'][i] = component ['long_name']
            break
    
    for component in row['geocode_data']['geometry']:
      if component['location']:
            df['location_lng'][i] = int(component['location']['lng'])
            df['location_lat'][i] = int(component['location']['lat'])
  
df.to_csv('test10.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

##Here is a sample of the google data that I get in the name of geodata

```
{'geometry': {'viewport': {'southwest': {'lng': 4.947849719708499, 'lat': 52.36571761970851}, 'northeast': {'lng': 4.950547680291502, 'lat': 52.3684155802915}}, 'location': {'lng': 4.9491987, 'lat': 52.3670666}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP'}, 'address_components': [{'long_name': '114', 'types': ['street_number'], 'short_name': '114'}, {'long_name': 'Zeeburgerpad', 'types': ['route'], 'short_name': 'Zeeburgerpad'}, {'long_name': 'Amsterdam-Oost', 'types': ['sublocality_level_1', 'sublocality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Amsterdam-Oost'}, {'long_name': 'Amsterdam', 'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Amsterdam'}, {'long_name': 'Amsterdam', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Amsterdam'}, {'long_name': 'Noord-Holland', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political'], 'short_name': 'NH'}, {'long_name': 'Netherlands', 'types': ['country', 'political'], 'short_name': 'NL'}, {'long_name': '1019 AE', 'types': ['postal_code'], 'short_name': '1019 AE'}], 'place_id': 'ChIJD14pyz8JxkcRF1Kpg8opql4', 'formatted_address': 'Zeeburgerpad 114, 1019 AE Amsterdam, Netherlands', 'types': ['street_address']}
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: line 99, in <module>
  if 'location' in component ['lat']:

builtins.TypeError: string indices must be integer

Comment: 'for component in row['geocode_data']['geometry']:
            if 'location' in component ['lat']:'

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible typo in your code:

```
for component in row['geocode_data']['geometry']:
        if 'location' in component ['lat']:
            df['location_lng'][i] = component['lng']
```

I believe you want to be looking for component['lng'] there.

If that doesn't solve it, can you print out df['location_lng'] so we can see exactly what type it is?

Comment: So I am still getting the same error. giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to 'location' seems to be incorrect. Try this:

```
for component in row['geocode_data']['geometry']:
    if component['location']: # Note: NOT: if 'location' in component ['...']
        df['location_lng'][i] = component['location']['lng'] 
        df['location_lat'][i] = component['location']['lat']
```

Update:
It seems the actual problem is the output 'array' being used.
You are assigning the following output:

```
df['location_lat']=''
```

Then you are assigning:

```
df['location_lat'][i]=...
```

which is actually:

```
''[i] = ...
```

which will result in the Type error noted. [I get "KeyError: 'location_lat'", but hey...]

Maybe try something like:

```
results = []
...
for ...
    df = {}
    ...
    df['location_lng'] = component['location']['lng'] 
    ...
    results.append(df)
```

Updated update:
Not having used Pandas, I am unsure how the df csv format is reflected; I will speculate, however, that if you remove your "# create new columns for the output CSV " section your DataFrame structure will not be corrupted.
ie: remove:

```
df['geocode_data'] = ''
df['address']=''
```

etc.

I may be barking up the wrong tree though.

Another update:
My simple test case is:

```
js = ... (json string as above)
data = json.loads(js)

component = data['geometry']
if component['location']:
    val = component['location']['lat']
    print val
```

which works fine for extracting the latitude.
So the issue shouldn't be with the 'if' portion.

Update (again...)
Ok - one more try: instead of:

```
df['geocode_data'][i] = reverseGeocode(...)
```

assign directly to a dictionary variable to do the data extraction. ie:

```
data = reverseGeocode(...)
```

Then extract the data as above and assign to your DataFrame as desired.

Comment: So the locations path has been corrected! Thank you but I am still getting the same error of  "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

Comment: Have you still got the 'in' part in the 'if' check? That will need to be removed

Comment: I copied it directly and checked if I miss anything but I still get the Error 
builtins.TypeError: string indices must be integers on the line if component['location']:

Comment: I am kinda confused of how to embed your new changes to my script. Can you please show me how. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I tried manipulating it a bit and adding it in. I am still getting the same error on the line of if component['locations']

Comment: Hey ChrisC73 Thank you so much for your help. Can you help me impede this changes to my code liste above? Thanks.

Comment: So the error just falls everytime I use the location field. I dont know if that helps but I am trying to convert into an integer.

Comment: Using int should be fine; but I am out of ideas. Good luck.